# Website changes content within a single page...?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I am sure this has been asked before, but I am unsure of what it is really called. I am fairly new to the web design scene, and was wondering what it's called and what is used when a website changes it layout within a single html document. Is this called AJAX? I have only seen AJAX being used to create onepagers, but not to create what I am talking about.

The concept I have seen before and am trying to accomplish includes in-page transitions, accomplished by a button trigger that switches the content in the page to another content.

How could this be accomplished? I am assuming it is simply CSS and JavaScript. I know of Barba.JS, but I am not familiar with using JS libraries just yet.

Comment: there a few framework out there, take a look at knockout, backbonejs, angular, reactjs, vuejs

Comment: You're describing a Single Page Application (SPA).